# Object Object error on JSOM Insertion Operation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, jsom

I had written the code to insert the values in sharepoint list,And I was unable to to perform the operation.When I check step by step using "alert" then I see error as "[Object Object]" .
     Below is my written JSOM Script,Can any one help me in knowing why I am facing the error and what's wrong in my below code

```
<script>
alert('start script');
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', addlistitems);

function addlistitems()
{

alert('in Add Function');
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var myList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PRF');
alert(myList);

}
</script>
```

Comment: ``alert`` can only show Strings.. quickly learn to use ``console.log`` (or .info or .error) statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

```
function createListItem(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```